# Why is express error handling 404 on all routes, even ones that work?

Tags: node.js, express

So I've set up a blank brand new express app using the express generator.

I added a console.log to the error handler:

```
// error handler
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        // set locals, only providing error in development
        res.locals.message = err.message;
        res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
        console.log(err); //<-- This is the added line
        // render the error page
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error');
    });
```

And then when hitting the index of my app I get this in the console:

```
GET / 200 9.521 ms - 170
GET /stylesheets/style.css 200 2.099 ms - 111
{ [Error: Not Found] status: 404 }
```

Surely this code shouldn't even be called when a successful route is it? Is this meant to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the request that's causing the 404 is for `/favicon.ico`. The other requests have been handled successfully (hence the 200 status that gets logged, right after the request path).